# sql server GO equivalent in oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am working on migration script for Oracle, I need to change table structure and then populate it with data.

I would like to do the structure changes first and then do the data.

In SQL Server I would use `GO` to separate the batches.

**Is there an SQL Server `GO` command equivalent in Oracle?**

Comment: `GO` separates batches not statements (and is a client tool functionality not database engine). `;` is the (often optional) statement delimiter in SQL Server too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's `;` and `/`

```
select * from user_tables;
/
```

Comment: the 2. is correct one. only semi colon can't start some command.